# EJS JSON.stringify with backslashes

Tags: json, node.js, ejs

I'm experiencing an issue that I solved the wrong way:

`var message = __message.create(<%- JSON.stringify(message).replace(/\\/g, '').replace(/"{/g, "'{").replace(/}"/g, "}'")%>);`

I need to do this in order to render a valid JSON. What am I missing? My JSON is valid on the server side.

Comment: What is wrong with `<%- JSON.stringify(message)%>` ?? May be the data in `message` would help!

Comment: Well, actually you're right and I don't understand... I tried that and it didn't work, I guess I tried `__message.Message.create('<%- JSON.stringify(message)%>');` instead of `__message.Message.create(<%- JSON.stringify(message)%>);` which works fine indeed.

Answer (score 0):

use single or double quotes

```
var message = __message.create('<%-JSON.stringify(message)%>')
message = JSON.parse(message)
```

Comment: If I do that it renders `var message = __message.create('[Object Object]')`, and obviously fails to parse.

Comment: Since message is an object, I needed to not use the *quotes* but directly `var message = __message.Message.create(<%- JSON.stringify(message)%>);`